# Need example to Fire SQL Queries,store Facebook FQL results in SQL database

Tags: php, sql, facebook

I am firing a query regarding events created by a particular user in Facebook.
Want to import the same in SQL.

Following is the result of FQL

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Demo Event", 
      "pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yi/r/zSnTif5Rf_V.png", 
      "start_time": "2013-07-07T00:00:00+0530", 
      "end_time": "2013-08-29T03:00:00+0530", 
      "location": "Kulraj Broadway", 
      "description": "Pls ignore"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Demo Event Pls ignore", 
      "pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yi/r/zSnTif5Rf_V.png", 
      "start_time": "2013-06-24T18:10:00+0530", 
      "end_time": "2013-06-27T21:10:00+0530", 
      "location": "NCPA Theatres", 
      "description": "NM NM "
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to know how to fire FQL in standalone app,store all this data in my SQL.
Help me out to implement the same.
Thanks!